# Mac doesn't allow to login as standard User after restart

Tags: macbook-pro, login

This is something unusual I have come across and can't seem to find a way to fix it. I didn't find any solution online as well.

I have two users, one admin and one standard

If I was to shutdown my laptop and switch it on again, I'd be presented with the list of these two users.
If I login to the standard user, it doesn't accept my correct password

However, if I login as the admin user and then either log out or switch user, then it allows me to login as standard user

I'm not sure why this behaviour occurs.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using the following laptop

> Macbook Pro - MacOs Sierra v. 10.12.6

Comment: Sure.  You're using FileVault, and the admin user is allowed to unlock the volume and the standard user is not.

Comment: So is there a way to get around this? If I have to login as admin everytime a standard user wants to login then this will require my presence all the time, unless I never switch it off

Comment: Add the standard logins as allowed users.  https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/enabling-users-for-filevault-2-with-a-non-enabled-admin-user-does-not-work-in-mavericks/